# LinearLayout.removeAllViews() doesn't work (IllegalStateException)

Tags: android

I'm trying to add empty footer (`LinearLayout`) to my `ListView` and fill this footer with my own view after:

```
private View footerButton;
private LinearLayout footer;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.rlist);

    footer=new LinearLayout(this);
    footer.setLayoutParams(new ListView.LayoutParams(ListView.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ListView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

    footerButton=((LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.footer_button, null, false);

    ListView list=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    list.addFooterView(footerButton,null,false);

    final UsersListAdapter adapter = new UsersListAdapter(this);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);

    //...

    new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            //Loading...

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                    footer.removeAllViews();
                    footer.addView(footerButton);
                }
            });
        }
    }.start();
}
```

But I get exception in line "footer.addView(footerButton);":

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
```

Why? As you know I call `removeAllViews()` before adding any views. How to fix it?

Comment: After adding  footer.removeAllViews(); still you getting exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you have added **footerButton** in your `ListView` object

Check out this line..

```
list.addFooterView(footerButton,null,false);
```

So, now footerButton has a parent i.e list..  and so you get error while adding to your `LinearLayout` footer

Try `removeView()` for list...